# how to login with python

Tags: python, html, authentication

I'd like to log in to a platform where the HTML is

```
<form id="loginbar" action="/?page=login&amp;ref=%2F%3Fpage%3Ddashboard" method="post">
    <input style="margin-right:4px;" class="input corner-all" name="email_adress" value="" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" type="email">
    <input class="input corner-all" name="password" value="" placeholder="Passwort" type="password">
    <input class="submit corner-right" value="" type="submit">
</form>
```

I tried several different requests, but none of them worked.

The last one was

```
def rein ( mypage , email , pw ) :
    payload = {
        'action' : 'login' ,
        'email' : email ,
        'password' : pw
    }
    myp = mypage + '/?page=login'
    with requests.session ( ) as c :
        c.post ( mypage , data = payload )
        response = c.get ( myp )
    return response , True
```

Comment: You can try to first get it to work with a curl command, which should be easier, and then use [this](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to get the correct python code.

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: your payload dict is incorrect, data should match the `name` attributes in the form so you need 2 items in the dict: `email_adress` and `password`

Comment: @chade_ that seems a little heavy handed.

Answer (score 0):

Some points,

- Pay attention to the form's 'action' attribute, it's where the form gets submitted.
  If the form has no action the data will be sent to the URL of the page that contains the form, but in this case it's `'/?page=login&amp;ref=%2F%3Fpage%3Ddashboard'`.
- Pay attention to the 'name' attribute of the form fields and use that name in your POST data.
  For example, the 'email' key in `payload` should be 'email_adress'.
- Make sure to include all form fields in your POST data.
  If the form has any hidden fields you'll have to submit them too.
- Sometimes you may have to set or change HTTP headers (usually User-Agent and Referer).
  You can do that with the `headers` parameter or the `headers` attribute of the `session` object.
- Sometimes your client must be able to run javascript in order to login.
  `requests` doesn't execute js, so in that case you'll have to use `selenium` or similar clients.

An example,

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com'
mypage = url + '/?page=login&ref=/?page=dashboard'
email, pw = 'my_email', 'my_password'
payload = {
    'email_adress': email,
    'password': pw
}
s = requests.session()
s.post(mypage, data=payload)

print(s.cookies)
```